# Proof on Co-Reflexive then Symmetric

Tags: logic, proof-writing

Prove that if $R$ is co-reflexive then $R$ is symmetric.
I know that you assume the hypothesis (step 1) then define Co-reflexive (step 2) then use the Rule of Substitution to end up with $xRy \Rightarrow x=y$.  I am unsure how to proceed to end up with $xRy \Rightarrow yRx$
Co-reflexive is defined as xRy -> x=y

**I apologize that I am not familiar with the proper formatting of this website

Comment: I can fill in some of the blanks of your question.  Presumably $R$ is a relation and you want to prove it's symmetric.  But I'm not familiar with the term "Co-reflexive."  Please define it **by editing the definition into the question**, rather than answering in a comment.

Comment: I've removed the proof theory tag - it refers to [a specific subfield of mathematical logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_theory).

Answer (score 1):

You have the right idea, but seem to be using substitution at the wrong point.

- Take $\forall x\forall y ~.(x\mathrm Ry\to x=y)$ as a premise. (Eg that $\mathrm R$ has Co-Reflexivity)

  - Take some arbitrary $a,b$ .

    - Assume for that $a\mathrm Rb$.
    - From that derive *something*.
    - **Now** use *that* to derive $b\mathrm Ra$ by rule of substitution.
  - Discharge the assumption, to deduce that $a\mathrm Rb\to b\mathrm Ra$.
- Finally, generalise to obtain: $\forall x\forall y~.(x\mathrm Ry\to y\mathrm Rx)$, which is that $\mathrm R$ has Symmetry.